# Understanding handwritten text on a painting

Tags: translation, calligraphy, handwriting

I've been given a painting by a Chinese university professor many years ago. There is some handwriting on it and I always wondered what the text on it says. My Chinese is very basic so I gave OCR a try but it only resulted in some random numbers.
Maybe someone could understand the handwriting?
[image]

Comment: (花?)貓圖：- 武(澤?)大學 - 東(??)

Comment: I see 竹貓圖，武漢大學，車英. The bottom-right corner is not legible to me, I only see (maybe) 【弟】.

Comment: @dROOOze that totally makes sense, it was gifted to me at Wuhan University and it shows a panda under some bamboo. I'm trying to match the characters to the painting:
Top: 圖貓 - but where is 竹? Is it part of the painted leaves?
Middle: ?
Bottom: 大學 - are the two strokes at the bottom left (´\) the character 大? And 武漢 is in the red seal?

Comment: @SamWeber It would help if you knew what your professor's name was. I'm not confident in the signature or seal; I think the signature says 車英 and the bottom-left seal says 車英之印, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @dROOOze thank you so much! Unfortunately, I don't remember his name but I'm fine with knowing that it's his signature. Your text overlay is brilliant btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

> 竹貓圖
> *Painting of bamboo and cat(?)s*

> 武漢大學
> [*Wǔhàn University*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuhan_University)

I can't read the artist's signature or the seals.